# Determine if a member call is virtual in the Clang AST

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I'd like to write an analyzer that counts `virtual` function calls by looking at the C++ AST (output of `-ast-dump`), but I'm having difficulty determining which function calls are `virtual` and which are not. Here's an example piece of code:

```cpp
struct A {
    A() {}
    virtual int foo() { return 0; }
};
struct B : public A {
    B() {}
    //virtual int foo() { return 3; }
};

struct C : public B {
    C() {}
    virtual int foo() { return 1; }
};

int test(C* c) { 
    return c->foo() + c->B::foo() + c->A::foo();
}
```

In my initial implementation, I simply check whether or not the function being called is `virtual` using `expr->getMethodDecl()->isVirtual()` but (from what I understand) the calls in `c->B::foo()` and `c->A::foo()` are not actually `virtual` so it isn't sufficient to ask if the function being called is `virtual`.

When I dump the AST from this piece of code, I get the following tree for `test`:

```
`-FunctionDecl 0x1d33620 <line:19:1, line:21:1> line:19:5 test 'int (C *)'
  |-ParmVarDecl 0x1d33558 <col:10, col:13> col:13 used c 'C *'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x1d339f0 <col:16, line:21:1>
    `-ReturnStmt 0x1d339e0 <line:20:5, col:47>
      `-BinaryOperator 0x1d339c0 <col:12, col:47> 'int' '+'
        |-BinaryOperator 0x1d338a8 <col:12, col:33> 'int' '+'
        | |-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x1d33778 <col:12, col:19> 'int'
        | | `-MemberExpr 0x1d33748 <col:12, col:15> '<bound member function type>' ->foo 0x1d31c80
        | |   `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x1d33730 <col:12> 'C *' <LValueToRValue>
        | |     `-DeclRefExpr 0x1d33710 <col:12> 'C *' lvalue ParmVar 0x1d33558 'c' 'C *'
        | `-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x1d33848 <col:23, col:33> 'int'
        |   `-MemberExpr 0x1d33800 <col:23, col:29> '<bound member function type>' ->foo 0x1d02400
        |     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x1d33888 <col:23> 'A *' <UncheckedDerivedToBase (A)>
        |       `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x1d33868 <col:23> 'B *' <UncheckedDerivedToBase (B)>
        |         `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x1d337d8 <col:23> 'C *' <LValueToRValue>
        |           `-DeclRefExpr 0x1d33798 <col:23> 'C *' lvalue ParmVar 0x1d33558 'c' 'C *'
        `-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x1d33978 <col:37, col:47> 'int'
          `-MemberExpr 0x1d33930 <col:37, col:43> '<bound member function type>' ->foo 0x1d02400
            `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x1d33998 <col:37> 'A *' <UncheckedDerivedToBase (B -> A)>
              `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x1d33908 <col:37> 'C *' <LValueToRValue>
                `-DeclRefExpr 0x1d338c8 <col:37> 'C *' lvalue ParmVar 0x1d33558 'c' 'C *'
```

From looking this, it seems that the `UncheckedDerivedToBase` cast is marking places where the function call is non-`virtual`. Is this always the case? Should I always consider a call of the form `CXXMemberCallExpr (MemberExpr (ImplicitCastExpr<UncheckedDerivedToBase> e)))` to be a non-`virtual` call? Are there other patterns that would indicate non-`virtual` function calls? Is there any more robust way to determine this fact?

**EDIT**: Some more investigation suggests that the above hypothesis that `UncheckedDerivedToBase` is not sufficient. This code:

```cpp
struct A {
    virtual int foo() { return 100; }
};
struct B : public A {
    virtual int foo() { return 10; }
};

int test(B* b) {
    return b->foo() + b->B::foo();
}
```

seem to produce exactly the same AST node (at least indistinguishable on the console) for both calls, but the semantics should be different according to the standard if `b` is actually a derived class, e.g. `C` above.

Comment: Why did you conclude that `c->B::foo()` and `c->A::foo()` are not virtual?

Comment: This is the semantics of C++. This syntax is how you do "super" calls in C++. So the resolution doesn't go to the most derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinguishing factor is `hasQualifier` on the `MemberExpr` of the callee object. If `hasQualifier` is `true`, then the function call is non-`virtual`.